# How to present github api fetch data as links?

Tags: javascript, github

Is it possible to wrap `< a href="" < /a>`  around the fetch result in order to present the data as hyperlinks in tables?

```
output += `
            <tr>
              <td>${"Result: " + data.url}</td>
            </tr>
          `;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always put an anchor tag in the string.

```
output += `
            <tr>
              <td>Result <a href="${data.url}">link from github</a></td>
            </tr>
          `;
```

Or if your object is in array you can map it

```
var data = [{url: "some-link", "urlName": "link from github"}];

data = data.map(item =>{

   item.url = `<a href="${item.url}">${item.urlName}</a>`;

   return item;
})
```